# I am using .upper in my defined function , but it do not work to uppercase the string. Can anyone tell me whats wrong in my code?

Tags: python, uppercase

```
def Upper_case(name):
    name.upper()
    return name
    

x=Upper_case('hello')
print(x)
```

Comment: To format code select it and type ctrl-k,  [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Answer (score 0):

---

Even though you are calling `name.upper()` you are not storing it back in name.
Use `name = name.upper()` instead.